# How to stop MacOS from automatically sharing tabs to other devices I'm logged in to?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox

I have two laptops connected to the same Wi-Fi network. I've been using the first device for a few years, and have logged in to my Firefox account in the browser. The second device is brand new, and I'm yet to log in to my Firefox account even once.

However, when I open a website on Firefox on either of the laptops, it gets shared to the other laptop after a few seconds. I've been able to reproduce this with multiple websites, so it's unlikely to be a bug in the website. Chrome and Safari are not affected by the issue.

As I have not logged in to my Firefox account on the new device, I am wondering if there is some sort of "network scan and share" that's at play? How do I stop this?

Update:

My partner's device with Chrome is also affected. Any tab that's opened on Chrome on their ipad is showing up on their laptop with the tooltip "From ipad".

---

Here's a screencast of the issue as seen on the new device: https://recordit.co/oAHcvuHUuh

Tooltip on hover:

[image: Tooltip on hover]

Menu option on right click:

[image: Menu option on right click]

Sync is disabled:

[image: Sync is disabled]

**Relevant info:**

| . | Old Device Affected by issue | New Device Affected by issue | Old Device Unaffected by issue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Firefox version | 100.0.2 | 100.0.2 | 100.0.2 |
| Logged in to Firefox account | Yes - mine | No - none | Yes - mine |
| MacOS | 11.5.2 | 12.4 | 12.1 |
| Logged in to Apple account | Yes - mine | Yes - mine | Yes - partner's |

Comment: Hi John! Sync is already disabled, as I've not logged in yet. I've also tried restarting both the laptops already.

Comment: Looks like it's a Mac issue. Opening tabs on Chrome in an ipad are showing up in the laptop now. I've updated the question to include this new info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable Handoff under System Preferences/General.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it!